# Command to open several tabs of powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal

Every time I turn on the computer I need to open several tabs of powershell to run different programs, more or less like this:

[image]

So my question is if there is any command to open them using a script doing something like:

```
open_tab && run_api inside_the_new_tab
open_tab && run_hub inside_the_new_tab
open_tab && run_bookingpad inside_the_new_tab
open_tab && run_dashboard inside_the_new_tab
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Now I am able to do something like this:

```
wt -w 0 nt cmd /k my_script.bat .
wt -w 0 nt cmd /k my_script_2.bat .
```

But I am not able to run it on Powershell (only cmd)

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell by itself doesn't have tabs; it's running in a terminal that has tabs (or not).<sup>1</sup>

In this case **Windows Terminal** is the "terminal" app hosting PowerShell. You can run `wt` to make it open a new tab with a specified profile, as documented in [Using command line arguments for Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments):

```
wt new-tab -p PowerShell
wt new-tab -p PowerShell -d C:\Projects\FooProj --tabColor "#ff0000"
wt new-tab -p MyCustomProfile \; new-tab -p CustomProfileTwo
```

<sup>1</sup> (It's exactly like how SuperUser.com doesn't have tabs but your web browser does.)

Comment: hi @user1686 I am working on it following the link you shared, and I am finding some advances, but some issues too. For example, I am able to do this: `wt -w 0 nt ping domain.com` but I am not able to run a ps1 script (nor even the dir command). On the other hand, I am able to do this: `wt -w 0 nt cmd /k my_script.bat` which works, but it is a cmd script not powershell.

Comment: Hmm, I think you need to specifically choose the PowerShell profile via `-p`, e.g. possibly `-p PowerShell dir` or `-p PowerShell something.ps1`? I would suggest using the Windows Terminal settings page (Ctrl+comma) to directly define a custom "BOOKINGPAD" profile via configuration, that's probably better than doing it via script.

Comment: hi again, ummmm I have created the profile (and it is very cool since I can modify the icon and a lot of things so it looks great), but when I do this `wt -w 0 nt -p BOOKINGPAD` I don't know how to run the command or the order I need to run (the content which right now I have on the script)

Comment: That's also configured via the profile, e.g. instead of plain `powershell.exe` I guess you want `powershell.exe -Command {.\foo.ps1} -NoExit`? (That's the PowerShell equivalent of "cmd /c" & "cmd /k".)

Comment: Hi :) but... where should I add that?? if I do in this way `wt -w 0 nt --title "HUB" --suppressApplicationTitle --tabColor "#6B8E35" -Command {bcdash.ps1} -NoExit` I get this error :  _-NoExit -inputFormat xml -outputFormat text']_ The other option I thought was to add it where the command line is defined on the profile settings, like this: `"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -Command {bcdash.ps1} -NoExit` but then I get `Unexpected token '-NoExit' in expression or statement.`

Comment: Yes, in the command line in the profile settings. I'm not very familiar with PowerShell, maybe it needs `-Command {...}` to always go last? (i.e. `-NoExit -Command {bcdash.ps1}` Or maybe WT has special treatment for {}, in which case `-NoExit -Command "bcdash.ps1"` should work. Try running powershell.exe manually from within Cmd.exe first, once it works put it in the profile.

Comment: ok ok!!! this is the solution I was looking for, please add as a solution and I will accept it. The short solution is: `wt -w 0 nt powershell.exe -Command {bcapi}` (bcapi is the ps1 script). Also you can add more variables, like the name or color of the tab and the profile (as fas as I know only for the icon) like this: `wt -w 0 nt --title "HUB" --suppressApplicationTitle --tabColor "#6B8E35" -p HUB powershell.exe -Command {bcapi} -NoExit`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution thanks to @user1686. The short solution is

```
wt -w 0 nt powershell -Command {bcapi}
```

(where bcapi is a ps1 script)

Alternatively, I added more flags to add color, the name of the tab and a profile (based on the powershell) to add an icon to the tabs, like this:

```
wt -w 0 nt --title "API" --suppressApplicationTitle --tabColor "#6B8E35" -p API wsl --cd ~/code/ndc-json-api/api/v1_2/
wt -w 0 nt --title "HUB" --suppressApplicationTitle --tabColor "#6B8E35" -p HUB powershell -Command {bcapi} -NoExit
wt -w 0 nt --title "BOOKINGPAD" --suppressApplicationTitle --tabColor "#8E4535" -p BOOKINGPAD powershell -Command {bfront} -NoExit
wt -w 0 nt --title "DASHBOARD" --suppressApplicationTitle --tabColor "#8E4535" -p DASHBOARD powershell -Command {bcdash} -NoExit
```

and now looks like this:
[image: powershell tabs created by script]